# Sometimes fragment lose activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can't to understand what's wrong, on my device app working nice, but sometimes in log(app users,sessions, crashes ... tracking via some service) i see app crash(NullPointerException), Toast cann't be run because activity variable is null.

Line 45 (**populateCats() method throws exception NullPointerException**)

```
    package package.name;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CatsList extends ListFragment implements OnTaskCompleted {
    Document doc;
    MainActivity activity;
    ArrayList<Cat> cats;

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Cat cat = cats.get(position);

        //SOME CODE
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new GetData(activity, this, false).execute(Jsoup.connect(MainActivity.url));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = (MainActivity) activity;
    }

    public void populateCats(){
        if(doc == null)
        {

            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Success....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //SOME CODE
    }


}
```

Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:98)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:254)
at PACKAGE_NAME.CatsList.populateCats(CatsList.java:64)
at PACKAGE_NAME.CatsList.taskCompleted(CatsList.java:92)
at PACKAGE_NAME.GetData.onPostExecute(GetData.java:61)
at PACKAGE_NAME.GetData.onPostExecute(GetData.java:12)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AndroidManifect.xml also contain- android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Comment: Try to change from the activity-variable to getActivity() in the toasts. You activityvariable is not set correctly... Is it possible to use the acticity-reference you get from onAttach(Activity activity)? Like this : this.activity = activity on the formentioned method?

Comment: WHY?
onAttach method calling before populateCats() and there i'll save reference to the activity..

p.s. i tried this method also

Comment: Try: this.activity = getActivity() in onActivityCreated(Bundle). See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: @ramaral can i to know why? ))

Comment: @ramaral i cann't to try it because on my phone app working nice (the exception i found in log of service which tracking my app)

i hope you understand my english )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've assumed correctly, the method **populateCats()** is called asynchronously by the **GetData** class. This means that there are several interleaving where the asynchronous procedure is still running when the user close the activity. This will cause a NPE because, if you have implemented the onAttach/onDetach correctly, you are clearing the activity reference when the fragment is detached after the activity is closed.

**As a good practice, you should always check the state of every Activity reference or getActivity() invocation and verify that they are not null before execute any other instruction.**

Comment: yes, you're right, GetData call another method which call populateCats();
Thanks )) i think you're right about my problem )